# Proving irreducibiltity of $f(X)=X^3 -2 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ at $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

My try:

Based on some answers about irreducibilitty i tried to show that if $\mathbb{L}$ is the splitting field of $f$ then, $[\mathbb{L}: \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=3$

By my calculations I get $\mathbb{L}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[3]{2})$, but i got to nowhere this way.

this way of proving make any sense?

Comment: I think your $\Bbb L$ is off. It should be $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt[3]2)$.

Comment: how $\sqrt{2}$ are related to the roots of $f$?

Comment: the roots of $f$ are $\sqrt[3]{2}$, $e^{2\pi i/3}\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $(e^{2\pi i/3})^2\sqrt[3]{2}$, then $\mathbb{L}=\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/3},\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[3]{2}$)

Comment: @Arthur: The splitting field is ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[3]2,e^{2\pi i/3})$, your comment is also off. ;)

Comment: @Arthur, sorry, but I can't see how can  $\sqrt{2}$ be extracted from the roots I've mentioned above, with just the other two generator you took is possible to get all $f$ roots, so when will I use $\sqrt{2}$ ??

Comment: @Arthur: I'm not sure how it helps. $x^4+1$ is reducible over ${\bf R}$, but has no root there. In any event, OP defined $\mathbf L$ as the splitting field of $f$ (to be fair, I'm not sure how that would have helped, either).

Comment: Splitting field over .... which field? The splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\sqrt{-3})$ (that's one of the first splitting fields in all textbooks). The splitting field over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ on the other hand....:-) Anyway, for the question about the degree of a field extension to make sense, you must have an extension of fields $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\sqrt{-3})$ is not an extension of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$.

Comment: So, @JyrkiLahtonen, this question does't even make sense?

Comment: I wouldn't put it that way :-) The way I read the title of your question the first time made me think that you are specifcally trying to prove that $x^3-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. That is true! But, then you veered off to its splitting field over $\Bbb{Q}$, which, while related and potentially useful, is not necessarily the main point. Anyway, tomasz' answer is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: A reducible polynomial of degree at most three has a root (over a field).

Comment: the roots of $f$ are $\sqrt[3]{2}$, $e^{2\pi i/3}\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $(e^{2\pi i/3})^2\sqrt[3]{2}$

Comment: @EduardoSilva So now try to prove that those numbers are not elements of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, and you're done.

Comment: @Arthur: That's true. But the easiest way of checking that they are not is to check that $x^3-2$ has no roots in ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt 2)$, so this is sort of circular.

Comment: You say "The easiest way to check". I say, by definition, that's the one thing you have to check, one way or another. It's not a circular argument, it's just a rephrasing of your hint to make it more directly relevant to Eduardo's comment.

Comment: @EduardoSilva: Forget what the roots are. Just use the definition to show that they are not in your field.

Comment: @tomasz, so the exercise consists of proving your claim, since the roots obviously does't belong to this field

Comment: @EduardoSilva: I think my claim and the fact that the roots don't belong in the field are equally obvious (or non-obvious).

Answer (score 2):

Eisenstein applies here, but you have to apply it with ingenuity. I assume that you know that $\sqrt2$ is a prime element of (the integers of) $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$. Now, I hope this sorites will convince you:
\begin{align}
X^3-2\text{ is irreducible over }\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)
&\Longleftrightarrow X^3-\frac12\text{ is irreducible over }\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\left(\frac X{\sqrt2}\right)^3-\frac12\text{ is irreducible over }\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow2\sqrt2\left[\left(\frac X{\sqrt2}\right)^3-\frac12\right]\text{ is irreducible over }\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow X^3-\sqrt2\text{ is irreducible over }\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)\,.
\end{align}

And with this, you conclude that the splitting field $\Bbb L$ is of degree six over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$.